# Android Room - How to return a List of Set for an entity

Tags: java, dao, android-room, android-architecture-components

I have the following Room query where I would like to get a List of Set of Strings.

```
@Query("SELECT books FROM students")
List<Set<String>> getAllBooks();
```

Here is a sample Student class.

```
@Data // Lombok
@Entity(tableName = "students"
public class Student {
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    private String studentId;

    @TypeConverter(SetToStringConverter.class)
    private Set<String> books;
}
```

Compiling this gives me `Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type`.

Consider I am maintaining each's student's books in a Set and have a TypeConverter for storing it into the database. SetToStringConverter converts a hashset of strings into a string and vice versa using ObjectMapper.

How can I retrieve all the books of all the students?

Answer (score 0):

Your converter should implement a function to convert " 'String' output from room query to 'SetofStrings' " otherwise it won't work.

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.TypeConverter;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class StringsHashSetConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    public static HashSet<String> toStringsHashSet(String value) {
        Type listType = new TypeToken<HashSet<String>>() {}.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(value, listType);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String toString(HashSet<String> list) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(list);
    }
}
```

**Also, you need to use a implementation of Set interface according to your requirement ( e.g. 'HashSet' ) for the field's data type to avoid any errors.**

```
@TypeConverter(StringsHashSetConverter.class)
private HashSet<String> books;
```

Comment: Yes, my converter does the same as you have mentioned. But still room did not like List<Set<String>> as return type.

Comment: You need to use accurate Set implementation i.e. HashSet. Room doesn't recognize interfaces i.e. Set.  Instead of List<Set<String>> try using ArrayList<HashSet<String>>.